# Non-model field is not validated in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, attr-accessor

I'm trying to add a validation of 'size' property for 'Creative' model. 'Creative' model is one-to-one related to the 'Ad', and it's field are displayed as a nested form in the 'Ads' form(code provided below).

The problem is, that when I'm actually saving the form, size is not validated — neither with format validator, nor with :presence validator(if I add one). At the same time, :filter property is validated.

Size is a non-model property, added with attr_acessor method and custom setters and getters.

Looking for a way to fix this code or any different solution to add a validation for non-model nested property will be much appreciated.

Controllers:

```
class Creative < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :size, :filter
  belongs_to :ad
  attr_accessor :size
  validates :size, :format => { :with => /^\d+x\d+$/, :message => "Incorrect size param. Should be [width]x[height], e.g. 320x50" }
  validates :filters, :presence => true

  def size
    "#{self.width}x#{self.height}"
  end

  def size=(size)
      @width, @height = size.split("x").map(&:to_i)
  end
end

class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :creative_attributes
  has_one :creative
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :creative

  validates_associated :creative
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ads
end
```

Form:

```
<%= simple_form_for [:rtb, @campaign, @ad], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
    <% if @ad.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation" class="alert alert-error">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@ad.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this ad from being saved:</h2>

            <ul>
                <% @ad.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
            <%= f.input :name  %>
            <%= f.simple_fields_for :creative do |creative_f| %>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Creative Settings</legend>
            <%= creative_f.input :size %>
            <%= creative_f.input :filters %>
            </fieldset>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```